# how to display the data returned by the controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, form-data

I am trying to display the data returned by the controller action:
my action:

```
public ActionResult RetreiveId()
{
    //....
    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { StatusCode = "1", JobId = NewJobId }));
}
```

My JSP incldes this form

```
<form id="write-cart-form" role="form" style="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="RetreiveId" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" 
data-ajax-success="alert('The ID is: ' + JobId); ">
```

Expected Results: A pup up saying : the ID is 1234

Actual Results The ID is undefined

here is the response of that request in the etwork tab
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the request and actual data that you post in browser F12 developer tool Network tab?

Comment: @FeiHan I did under network but i am not able to see the value being returned by the controller. However I see my action method returning a value

Comment: `not able to see the value being returned by the controller. However I see my action method returning a value` What's the actual response of that request in Network tab?

Comment: @FeiHan   updated the  description with the response of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by specfying the contenttype in the return of the action method for instance return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { StatusCode = "1", JobId = NewJobId }), "application/json");